# How to extract single paragraph from string Ruby

Tags: ruby

In my application I'm trying to extract the first paragraph from an article of text. How can I do this?

Comment: please show some code: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What do you mean by a "paragraph"? Newline-delimited string of text? Empty line-delimited string of text? <p> object in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be done the following way:

```
test =  <<PARAGRAPH
I've actually been using the latest version of JAWS (the popular Windows screen reader software for blind people) recently, as part of my work on HTML5. From a usability point of view it is possibly the worst software I have ever used. I'm still horrified at how bad the accessibility situation is.

For example, JAWS will happily take the last sentence of a paragraph, and the first sentence of the next paragraph, and run them into each other as one sentence, if there's no full stop at the end of the first paragraph. If you really want to make your Web pages more readable to blind users, forget longdesc or even alt, or even markup of any kind, just make sure you're using full punctuation! And that's just one example.
'
PARAGRAPH

puts test[/(.*)/]   # This will print the first paragraph.
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do:

```
>> str="<p>sadsda</p>"
=> "<p>sadsda</p>"
>> str.scan(/<p>(.*)<\/p>/)
=> [["sadsda"]]
>> str.scan(/<p>(.*)<\/p>/)[0]
=> ["sadsda"]
```

Comment: But what if the string does not include paragraph tags like this?